# А возможно ли как то подключить бд и пройтись по всем таблицам сразу?

Tags: java, mysql

```
String query="DELETE FROM users
```

и тут могут быть много таблиц в базе

```
WHERE id="+ID;
```

Можно ли как то пройтись сразу по всем трем таблицам, чтоб не писать трижды одну и ту же функцию?

Comment: Drop database {name};

Comment: он же вроде базу всю удаляет,  а мне надо чтоб именно нужный id в таблице , а таблиц в базе три .

Comment: Угу, базу целиком с данными и таблицами =) зато сразу в одно действие =) а не в целых три запроса =)